# Can a dual national of UK and Colombia enter Colombia with an ID and/or an expired Colombian passport?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, paperwork, dual-nationality, colombia, colombian-citizens

I have a British passport which is valid and a Colombian passport that is expired, my Colombian Identity card (Cedula) is valid. I will be travelling at the end of November to Colombia. Will I be allowed into Bogota, Colombia? I cannot tell whether there will be issues entering and have tried reaching out to the Colombian embassy but no luck so far.

**Edit:**

> I managed to reach the Colombian Embassy in London & Switzerland, they said they
>   have never encountered issues with Colombian citizens entering the
>   country on an expired passport, you may get a warning, however they did advice me to renew the Passport on entry. Additionally adviced, if a person has
>   sufficient time in the country of residence, get it renewed at the Embassy (Estimated 8-10 working
>   days, new passports get sent from Colombia) in my case i don't have enough time, or alternatively renew the passport at
>   Bogota on entry, for $160,000 pesos next day 24 hours. Cedula will be valid for travel within Colombian and exit, but you may have to pay a penalty on exit if you present an expired Colombian passport with the rest of your valid documents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From TIMATIC, the database used by airlines:

> Nationals of Colombia are allowed to enter with an expired passport.

and

> Passport Exemptions: Nationals of Colombia with a national ID card

So yes, an expired Colombian passport (or, alternatively, a valid *cédula*) is sufficient.

To exit Colombia, I was told by Colombian immigration on the phone a while ago that a valid *cédula* is sufficient, but not an expired passport.

Basically, bring your UK passport and Colombian *cédula* on this trip

Comment: Is this sufficient to leave Colombia? I have spoken to another Colombian Embassy abroad and they advised that i renew my passport in Bogota, which can be done within 24 hours or 48 hours depending on the service i request. I will add details to my question

Comment: @NewScientists I would email servicio.ciudadano@migracioncolombia.gov.co if I were you. I can do it for you if you don't feel you have the energy (my Spanish is sufficient for this)

Comment: @NewScientists A valid cédula should be enough (in fact, if nothing else, it definitely will be if changing planes in another MERCOSUR country on the way). But again, I'll email immigration and ask about both documents

Comment: Thank you so much for the help @Coke! really appreciated, I've emailed them directly as i don't want to use up your time but if you feel interested in the situation for sure email them too, would be interesting to hear.

Comment: @NewScientists Indeed it would be interesting, so I've mailed them too

Comment: @NewScientists My honest guess is you may as well leave your expired Colombian passport at home, and just bring your UK passport and Colombian cédula. As it's valid, I find it more likely it will be accepted for exit than an expired passport.

Comment: @NewScientists Just remembered I actually phoned immigration for someone in the same situation as you long ago, and they said an expired passport isn't valid for exit, but a valid cédula is. So yes, you can travel in and out with your UK passport and Colombian céedula

Comment: thank you so much for all the help! really appreciated